# Get backends associated to an API Management Service

Tags: azure, command-line-interface

Is there any way to get the list of backends of a specific API Management Service using Azure CLI?

[image]

[az apim documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/apim?view=azure-cli-latest) does not have any method to list the backends.

I tried to iterate the operations of one of the APIs, but they don't have the backend information. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

I have one API Management service named **`sriapim01`** with below **backends**:

[image]

> Note that, you can **only** use either **PowerShell** or **REST API** or **ARM templates** to list the backends of  API Management service.

In my case, I used below **PowerShell** commands and got backends list successfully like below:

```
$apimContext = New-AzApiManagementContext -ResourceGroupName "rgname" -ServiceName "APIM name"
Get-AzApiManagementBackend -Context $apimContext
```

**Response:**

[image]

To list the *backends* via REST API, you can **refer** below MS document:

[Backend - List By Service -  (Azure APIM) | Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/apimanagement/current-ga/backend/list-by-service?tabs=HTTP)

Comment: Thanks. I also had it in Powershell but was not sure if Azure CLI supported it or not. Thanks for the confirmation!